# Where can I find older versions of hadoop?

Tags: hadoop

I am looking for version 0.22.0  of hadoop (hadoop-0.22.0.tar.gz).

I visited the web site http://hadoop.apache.org/releases.html with full hopes but the link there leads me to description, but there is no download link for the version mention. For example, I clicked on the link "10 December, 2011: release 0.22.0 available ", which led me to the specific section in the page where details of this release is given.  Since no download link could be found in this section, I tried to click on "Hadoop 0.22.0 Release Notes .." link, which showed me "404 Not found" error. All other links in the same section is giving me the same error.

So the question is, from where I can download the older versions of hadoop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [archives](http://archive.apache.org/dist/hadoop/core/). In particular, see [hadoop-0.22.0](http://archive.apache.org/dist/hadoop/core/hadoop-0.22.0/).